components css vs index.css in react
I was trying to give same style on a same class name inside the index.css and like app.css file. Now I see that index.css file style is applied but the app.css is not .for example i write .class{background-color:red} inside the index.css and .class{background-color:blue} inside the app.css. Why index.css file's style is getting more priority
for example i write .class{background-color:red} inside the index.css and .class{background-color:blue} inside the app.css. Why index.css file style are getting more priority

When two css rules are matching the same element and setting the same styles, the priority depends on Specificity of the selectors, and then the order of the <link rel="stylesheet"> elements.
It's recommended to pick unique class names across your project, or use CSS Modules and have a preprocessor generate unique class names for you. That way, you don't have to manage conflicting CSS rules between components.
